# How to include a sass file in an index.js with webpack?

Tags: webpack

This is my webpack config file

```
var path = require('path');
var MDC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', '@material');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: "sass-loader!style-loader!css-loader",
                include: [
                    MDC_DIR
                ],
            }
        ],
    }
};
```

This is my `index.js` file

```
import * as mdc from 'material-components-web';
require('material-components-web/material-components-web.scss');
```

When I run webpack, it throws the following error:

```
ERROR in ./~/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss
Module parse failed: /Users/Me/project/mdc-babel-attempt/node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss Unexpected character '@' (17:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| //
|
| @import "@material/animation/mdc-animation";
| @import "@material/button/mdc-button";
| @import "@material/card/mdc-card";
 @ ./index.js 9:0-63
```

Which made me think it's not passing through the loader.

I even tried `require('sass-loader!style-loader!css-loader!material-components-web/material-components-web.scss');` with no luck:

```
ERROR in ./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss
Module build failed:
//
^
      Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in /Users/Me/project/mdc-babel-attempt/node_modules/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./index.js 9:0-99
```

Been trying to do this for a week now, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `MDC_DIR` that you include in the rule, does not match the actual module. The module is `material-components-web` (just as you import it and as the error shows), but you only apply the rule for `@material`. You can remove the `include` option entirely, because you'll always need to handle Sass files to be able to use them with webpack.

The other issue is that your loader order is wrong. The loaders are applied in reverse order (from right to left), in your case that's:

```
css-loader -> style-loader -> sass-loader
```

You definitely want the `sass-loader` to be applied before the `css-loader`, because it transforms Sass to CSS, otherwise it will error on any Sass syntax that is not valid CSS. Even when you only use CSS syntax (without the extra Sass features) you'll get an error because `style-loader` transforms CSS to JavaScript, and that gets passed to `sass-loader`. The `sass-loader` expects Sass and JavaScript is not valid Sass syntax, therefore it will throw an error.

Your rule should be:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader",
}
```

Or with the nicer webpack 2 syntax:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know, thanks for replying!

Comment: I got `File to import not found or unreadable: @material/animation/mdc-animation`. That line is the first one of [material-components-web/material-components-web.scss](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/packages/material-components-web/material-components-web.scss), the file I'm calling `require()` in my `index.js`. What am I missing?

Comment: I put `includePaths: ['node_modules']` in my `sass-loader` options, because mdc have it on their [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/c4411578d775da17c2c97d416863e5825cceb34d/webpack.config.js#L66). It worked.